Dirichlet problem for mean curvature equation
Let $\Omega$ be a uniformly convex domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with smooth boundary $\partial \Omega$. For any $\varphi \in C^{\infty} (\partial \Omega)$, is there a stictly convex smooth solution $u$ to the Dirichlet problem of prescribed mean curvature equation
\begin{aligned}
H(x) =&\; c, &\mbox{in}\; \Omega\\
u =&\; \varphi, &\mbox{on}\; \partial \Omega
\end{aligned}
where $H(x)$ is the mean curvature of the graph $(x, u(x))$ and $c> 0$ is a constant.
Is there anyone that remind me any references where this result is proved?

If we ignore "convexity" everywhere in your question, Gillbarg & Trudinger Theorem 16.11 gves:

For $\Omega$ a bounded $C^2$ domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$, the Dirichlet problem $H(\textrm{graph}(u)) = c$, $u|_{\partial\Omega} = \varphi$ is solvable (for all $\varphi$) if and only if the boundary mean curvature of $\partial\Omega$ satisfies $H_{\partial\Omega} \geq \frac{n}{n-1}|c|$.


I think that for $\Omega= B_1$ and $\varphi =0$, no solution exists (convex or not) for $|c|$ large as can be seen by analyzing rotationally symmetric CMC surfaces.

If $c$ is very（arbitrary） small, any chance to have a strictly convex solution? If the solution is not convex, is it convex near the boundaty $\partial \Omega$ at least?

Doesn't convexity near the boundary follow automatically by continuity of the hessian?

You mean the Hessian of u is positive definite on the boundary? Under a principal coordinate system at $0 \in \partial \Omega$, we know $u_{\alpha\beta} = \varphi_{\alpha\beta} - (u_n - \varphi_n) \rho_{\alpha\beta}$ at $0$, where $\varphi$ is extended to a striclty convex function on $\Omega$ and $x_n = \rho (x')$ is $\partial \Omega$. Why $(u_{\alpha\beta}){1\leq \alpha, \beta \leq n-1}$ is positive definite unless we can extend $\varphi$ to a strictly convex function with $\varphi_n- u_n \geq 0$ at $0$. Even we can do this, why $(u{ij})_{1\leq i,j \leq n}$ is positive definite at $0$?

Could you please tell me more details or refer any references to me?

Sorry probably my last comment was not correct.

Thank you for your helpful comments.

In $\mathbb{R}^3$, the Plateau problem for constant mean curvature surfaces was solved in
Hildebrandt, S., On the Plateau problem for surfaces of constant mean curvature, Commun. Pure Appl. Math. 23, 97-114 (1970). ZBL0181.38703.
Now, this version does not match directly with what you asked:

Compared to what you asked about, this is only about $n = 2$
You are only looking at the graphical case, whereas Hildebrandt's result does not make the assumption that the resulting surface is obtained as a graph over a hyperplane.

But potentially tracing forwards and backwards from this paper on MathSciNet will get you something more akin to the precise statement you are asking about.
